# EPiserver: ICurrentPage does not have a definition for ContentLink

Tags: c#, episerver

Our Editors in EPiserver would like to be able to modify the hreflang links of each page as needed. So I would like to modify our pages and enable an override of the default hreflang feature in episerver.

I have started by trying to write my own htmlhelper that will put together the hreflang for me so that I can modify it later.

In the file HtmlHelpers.cs I have started with the following:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks()
{
    var pageLanguagesBranches = ContentRepository.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>(ICurrentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
    var availablePageLanguages = FilterForVisitor.Filter(pageLanguagesBranches).OfType<PageData>();

    // Dictionary<String, String>
    return null;
}
```

Visual Studio is informing me that `ICurrentPage` does not have a definition for `ContentLink`.

I would appreciate any help as I am not that familiar with EPiserver.

**Update 1:**

The following was suggested:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this BasePage currentPage)
        {
            var pageLanguagesBranches = ContentRepository.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>(currentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
            var availablePageLanguages = FilterForVisitor.Filter(pageLanguagesBranches).OfType<PageData>();

            // Dictionary<String, String>
            return null;
        }
```

Instead of `BasePage` We have `StandardPage` which inherits from `SitePageData` which inherits from `PageData`. I tried all three but that didn't work, Visual Studio underlines this section `ContentRepository.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>`with the following message:

> Unsupported internal API....
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or
>   property
>   `ContentRepository.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>(ContentReference)`

Comment: Just a side note to approach itself - the way you've chosen will work only for cases when you control rendering of the links; but there are many cases when you don't - for example XHTML property / TinyMCE. I advice looking into the concept of routing, so you can override global way EPiServer uses to render links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the consept of a BasePage (you should) that all your pages inherit from, you can try the following:

```
 public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this BasePage currentPage)
    {
        IContentRepository repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
        var pageLanguagesBranches = repo.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>(currentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
        var availablePageLanguages = FilterForVisitor.Filter(pageLanguagesBranches).OfType<PageData>();

        // Dictionary<String, String>
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it but didn't work. See my Update 1 above.

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed your initial problem. But I have edited the answer so it will compile

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just had to change BasePage to PageData. While I see that pageLanguagesBranches contains 3 values (the three languages that we have). availablePageLanguages is null. I will have to find out why.

Comment: Ok, great:) Feel free to upvote and mark as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to call the GetLanguageBranches method without first obtaining an instance of IContentRepository.
You can inject IContentRepository to the static extension class like this:

```
private static readonly Injected<IContentRepository> _contentRepository = default(Injected<IContentRepository>);
```

Then rewrite line 3 of your update to something like this:

```
var pageLanguagesBranches = _contentRepository.Service.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>(currentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
```